# Crystal Reports does not execute all database queries if first query returns no results

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report (using CR 2008) that has three database queries (the below is sourced from the "Show SQL" menu option)

```
MYSERVER
"mydb"."dbo"."run_report";1 {d '2000-01-01'}, {d '2015-01-01'}, 'A12345'


MYSERVER
select SUser_SName() as [CurrentUser]


MYSERVER
select parent_name from containers where id = '{?@id}'
```

None of these queries depend on each other, although the first and last queries use the same input parameter - `@id` (which is `A12345` in this example)

The above works fine when the `run_report` stored procedure returns > 0 results. When it returns no results (but no actual errors as far as I can tell), the second and third SQL queries don't appear to be executed as their results (which are inserted into the report as fields) are just blank.

I can see two possible approaches to the issue:

1. Reorder the SQL queries so that the ones that will always return a result run first, and the stored procedure (which may return no results) runs last; or
2. Somehow I make Crystal Reports continue on its merry way even if the stored procedure query doesn't return any rows.

...but I'm not sure how to achieve either approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cross-posted on the SAP forums and got [this answer](http://scn.sap.com/message/15810565).

There are two possible solutions

1. Make the stored procedure return a single row of all NULL values when there's no actual results.
2. Split the report up into one main report and two sub-reports. The Stored Procedure runs in the main report, and each of the other queries runs in its own sub-report

I used solution #1 (as it was less work in my case) and it worked fine. I changed my stored procedure into a SELECT INTO, with results getting put into a temporary table. I could then go:

```
-- Do the main SELECT INTO query first, then...

-- Check if temporary table is empty
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM #report WHERE Id IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        -- If the source table you SELECTed from had NOT NULL columns,
        -- you'll need to alter them prior to inserting your row of NULLS
        ALTER TABLE #report ALTER COLUMN Name VARCHAR(255) NULL
        -- Rinse and repeat for other affected columns

        -- Then insert the row of NULLS
        INSERT INTO #report VALUES(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
    END

-- Return the contents of the report
SELECT * FROM #report
```